# Authorize Timeline app to user's profile and then do OpenGraph action

Tags: javascript, facebook, authentication, facebook-graph-api, dialog

I'm pretty new to Facebook development, so been trying to read up on older questions but still a bit lost =\

Here's one that I'm struggling with:

Currently I have an app with several defined Open Graph actions i.e. "ask a question".  Is there a way to provide a dialog box for users that do not have the app yet, so that after they authorize the app, it'll go ahead and do the OG action?  Ideally, it'd happen smoothly and without multiple dialog boxes.

OG action:

```
FB.api(
    "/me/beta_sandbox:ask?question=http://example/question/1",
    'post',
    function(response) {
    if (!response || response.error) {
        alert('Sorry, your question was not shared: '+response.error);
    } else {
        alert('Your question was successfully shared!');
    }
});
```

Solution: redirect uri?

Any help would be greatly appreciated =)

Answer (score 0):

You should authorize users prior to publishing an action.

You can nest the publishing of an action within [`FB.getLoginStatus`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/) method to publish action for logged in users and bring login dialog for user who not connected with app or logged out of Facebook:

```
var publishAction = function(){
  FB.api('/me/beta_sandbox:ask?question=http://example/question/1', 'post',
    function(response) {
      if (!response || response.error) {
        console.log('question was not shared', response);
      } else {
        console.log('question was successfully shared!');
      }
    }
  );
}

FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // User is authenticated, Publish Action
    publishAction();
  } else {
    // Bring Login Dialog to authenticate the user
  }
}
```

You also may leverage [`FB.login`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/) method to publish action after user is logged in (for users who already logged in dialog will not be opened and closed immediately  and callback will be called):

```
FB.login(function(response) {
  if (response.authResponse) {
    // User is authenticated, Publish Action
    publishAction();
  } else {
    // User declined authentication
  }
});
```